# Can I use いただきます next to another word?

Tags: food

こんにちは。

I'm from Venezuela and I'm studying in a culinary school located in Amazonas. I plan to use some Japanese recipes as part of my project and I've been thinking about a name for my thesis for a while. I thought about "Amazonas, itadakimasu" or "Itadakimasu Amazonas"; however, whenever I hear いただきます it is always said alone and never with other words.  For example "おかあさんいただきます". I'm aware that this is beyond a simple "bon apetit" because it's a way say thank you for everything you're about to eat ( everything in your plate).

I'm also aware that most of the people that will read the thesis will not really care about it (not because it's not important but because they won't understand), but I want to know if it's grammatically correct because I do care.

Btw, the tittle will be written in romaji as shown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

いただきます said before a meal is basically just a custom, and it's usually addressed to no one in particular, although you may think you're thanking to "everything" by saying it. But if you have a particular existence (person, god, place, or whatever) you are specifically thanking to, it's perfectly fine to add the name of the "giver" after or before いただきます.

いただきます literally means "(I) will receive (it)". You can use this when you show your gratitude after receiving something from someone who is higher than you. (The first half of the phrase is いただく, which is a [humble verb](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/honorific) meaning "receive".)